# Список с объектами в скрипте C# в Unity3D очищается при загрузке скриптов

Tags: c#, unity3d, объекты

В Unity3D создал объект `NotSaveObject` и список `public List<NotSaveObject> listOfNotSaveObjects = new List<NotSaveObject>();`, добавил туда несколько таких объектов, но после того, как сделал никак не влияющее на этот список изменение и вернулся в Unity3D, после перезагрузки скрипта этот список очистился; так происходит после каждой загрузки этого скрипта.
Если использовать не список из этих объектов, а

```
public List<bool> listOfFields1 = new List<bool>();
public List<int> listOfFields2 = new List<int>();
```

или

```
public List<UnityEngine.Vector3> listOfOtherObjects = new List<UnityEngine.Vector3>();
```

то списки будут работать нормально.
Пишу скрипты в VisualStudio, она не показывает никаких ошибок или предупреждений в этом коде:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

namespace Developer.Scripts
{
    public struct NotSaveObject : IEquatable<NotSaveObject>
    {
        public bool field1 { get; set; }
        public int field2 { get; set; }

        public NotSaveObject(bool field1, int field2)
        {
            this.field1 = field1;
            this.field2 = field2;
        }

        public static bool operator ==(NotSaveObject lhs, NotSaveObject rhs)
        {
            return lhs.Equals(rhs);
        }

        public static bool operator !=(NotSaveObject lhs, NotSaveObject rhs)
        {
            return !lhs.Equals(rhs);
        }

        public bool Equals(NotSaveObject notSaveObject)
        {
            return field1 == notSaveObject.field1 &&
                   field2 == notSaveObject.field2;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (!(obj is NotSaveObject))
                return false;
            NotSaveObject notSaveObject = (NotSaveObject)obj;
            return notSaveObject != null &&
                   field1 == notSaveObject.field1 &&
                   field2 == notSaveObject.field2;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            var hashCode = 1597875139;
            hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + field1.GetHashCode();
            hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + field2.GetHashCode();
            return hashCode;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавь `[System.Serializable]` перед `public struct NotSaveObject`